# Xero integration with OAuth 2.0 credentials

Tags: civixero

Seeing some changes in the Xero process of creating a "new App" to use for synching with CiviCRM.

Specifically it now requires an

- OAuth 2.0 redirect URI

but also, unless my eyesight is failing, i no longer see where we are meant to upload the .cer we create on our hosting server.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

we’re almost done moving over xero to oauth 2.0 and can share the code/instructions in the next few days if that works for you?

Comment: absolutely. v happy to help with testing. i have 2 'test/demo' sites to set up so would be excellent timing to help.

Comment: Parvez and you able to share the instructions here / on the documentation?